# Can dissimilarity matrix be used instead of data frame when we have both categorical and continuous variables?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, categorical-data

I'm new to R.I have a data frame which has both continuous and categorical variables,My questions is: can I use dissimilarity matrix instead of data frame when in some functions just numeric matrix or data frames are accepted?For example when I want to use lofactor() which is the function for LOF algorithm and can be applied just on numeric data while my data has some categorical variables,Can I use the dissimilarity matrix of my data which is numeric?

Any little help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the dissimilarity index you're using allows for continuous and categorical data, yes.

Comment: I use daisy() in order to compute the dissimilarity matrix for me choosing metric="gower".Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

The DMwR `lofactor` *implementation* is slow and too limited.

But the Local Outlier Factor LOF allows any dissimilarity to be used.

You probably just have to **write the code yourself**, or use a better implementation such as ELKI instead of DMwR.